# aligning 3 items next to each others using bootstrap react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, flexbox, grid

so basically i have these photos:

[image: images]

i have created a postItem component which is just the structure of the image and i'm calling it from the api.js component from data using .map
the problem is, i used bootstrap grid system and used row and col-lg-4 to display each 3 on one line but its not working.

postItem.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function PostItem ({src,thumbnailUrl,onClick,title}) {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid text-center">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-4">
            <img src={src} onClick={onClick} alt="small post"></img>
            <div>{title}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}

export default PostItem;
```

api.js:

```
<div>
            <div>{newPhotosLocally.map(picture => 
                 <PostItem 
                 key={picture.id}
                 src={picture.thumbnailUrl} 
                 thumbnailUrl={picture.thumbnailUrl} 
                 onClick={() => showPicture(picture.url,picture.id,picture.title)}
                 title={picture.title}/>

            )}</div>
            </div>
```

hope you can help me guys i've been stuck on this for an entire day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do something like this

```
<div className="col-lg-4 d-flex">
    {newPhotosLocally.map(picture =>
        <PostItem
            key={picture.id}
            src={picture.thumbnailUrl}
            thumbnailUrl={picture.thumbnailUrl}
            onClick={() => showPicture(picture.url, picture.id, picture.title)}
            title={picture.title} />

    )}
</div>
```

because the reason is everytime iterate loop thus it will every time create new row . this is the reason you didn't get your images not align even we added display flex property ..

now remove unnecessary code from image portion .

hope you'll get it .

Comment: it didn't work tried it now :/ the result is that they became so close to each other but still in a column display

Comment: i made one but its not working its working fine on my machine but on sandbox its not loading the images: https://codesandbox.io/live/gqr0Y if you can replicate it on ur machine not on sandbox it would be great

Comment: @M.I i have updated the code please check .  with reason if you still didn't get than feel free to ask .